# I get almost same performance on both Tesla K40 and Tesla K80

Tags: performance, cuda, gpu

I have developed two CUDA kernels. One is a memory-bound kernel and the other is compute-bound. The kernels, first have been optimized on Tesla K40 and I am doing a performance test on both Tesla K40 and Tesla K80 now to compare their performance results. However, I am really confused because I get almost same performance on both boards while K80 provides almost 2x wider theoretical bandwidth and DP peak performance. I also tested with different number of threads per block but again did not see any tangible performance improvement on Tesla K80 (around 2%) comparing to Tesla K40.

I compile the code using following flags:

On Tesla K40:

```
nvcc --cudart static --relocatable-device-code=false -gencode arch=compute_35,code=compute_35 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -link -o  "test"
```

On Tesla K80:

```
nvcc --cudart static --relocatable-device-code=false -gencode arch=compute_37,code=compute_37 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -link -o  "test"
```

Theoretically, I should get higher performance on Tesla K80 but I do not have any idea why that does not work.

Thanks for any answer or comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, I am really confused because I get almost same performance on both boards while K80 provides almost 2x wider theoretical bandwidth and DP peak performance.

Tesla K80 only provides those benefits when you have a code that can take advantage of multiple GPUs.  You appear to be running a single kernel (launch) for your tests, and a K80 will not run a single kernel (launch) any faster than a K40.

A K80 is in fact two GPUs bundled into one physical unit.  Each of the two GPUs has about 80-90% of the performance of a single K40, so bundled together, it can offer almost twice the performance, but only on a multi-GPU aware code.

A K80 (compared to a K40)  will provide no benefit for a single kernel (launch) execution.

Comment: So K80 will be efficient only for multi-GPU code, right? My code is a single GPU which the second kernel is executed after the first kernel execution finished.

Comment: Correct.  As a trivial test, you could launch two independent gemm operations using CUBLAS.  If you ran them on a single K40, one would run after the other, most likely.  If you ran them on a single K80, you could run them on two separate GPUs on the K80, so each could run at the same time, and it should take approximately half as long as the K40 test.